# Upgrade jquery version to 3.6.1, validation message go to a weird position

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all,sorry for my bad English.

I have to upgrade jquery version from 1.8.3 to 3.6.1.
There are some problems I already fixed.
I found when I use 3.3.0+ version the problem will happen.

Some input is validate[required] or use validationEngine.
But when I submit the form, the position of validation is weird looks like out of form.

The red arrow point the wrong position
[My website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxwlP.png)

Code example(The field of description) :

```java
if(descLength>82){
    $("#dtlDesc"+x).validationEngine('showPrompt', '<fmt:messagekey="function.JournalProcess.DescptTooLong"/>', '','topLeft', true);
    valid = false;
}else if(descLength<1){
    $("#dtlDesc"+x).validationEngine('showPrompt', '<fmt:message key="function.JournalProcess.FieldRequired"/>', '','topLeft', true);
    valid = false;
}
```

But the field which I use select2 is correct.

My JSP:

```
<table id="forms" class="jrTable">
    <tr>
        <th><fmt:message key="function.JournalProcess.SN"/></th>
        <th><fmt:message key="common.CreditDebit"/></th>
        <th><span><fmt:message key="function.JournalProcess.AccountBranch"/></span></th>
        <th><span><fmt:message key="function.CostCenterSetting.CostCenter"/></span></th>
        <th><span><fmt:message key="function.JournalProcess.Currency"/></span></th>
        <th><span><fmt:message key="function.JournalProcess.AccountId"/></span></th>
        <th><span><fmt:message key="function.JournalProcess.Payer"/></span></th>
        <th><span><fmt:message key="function.JournalProcess.Amount"/></span></th>
        <th><span><fmt:message key="function.JournalProcess.AmountLcy"/></span></th>
        <th><span><fmt:message key="function.JournalProcess.Description"/></span></th>
        <th><span><fmt:message key="function.AssetRegistration.VendorId"/></span></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I use append() to create a row of data.

I upgrade validationEngine.js from 2.6.2 to 3.0.0,the promblem still exist.
[ValidationEngine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine)

What should I do?
If I need to supply more information, please tell me.
Thanks a lot!